# Youtube Data v3 - How do I filter ChannelSections query by targeting

Tags: youtube-api, youtube-data-api

This query:

```
https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/channelSections?part=snippet%2CcontentDetails%2Ctargeting&channelId=UC-9-kyTW8ZkZNDHQJ6FgpwQ&key={YOUR_API_KEY}
```

returns lots of data like this:

```
{
   "kind": "youtube#channelSection",
   "etag": "\"iDqJ1j7zKs4x3o3ZsFlBOwgWAHU/oIyqO89jk-vcfHm5Kuz3sikdUzc\"",
   "id": "UC-9-kyTW8ZkZNDHQJ6FgpwQ.lc3PRFGaA4k",
   "snippet": {
    "type": "singlePlaylist",
    "style": "horizontalRow",
    "channelId": "UC-9-kyTW8ZkZNDHQJ6FgpwQ",
    "position": 0
   },
   "contentDetails": {
    "playlists": [
     "PLFgquLnL59alW3xmYiWRaoz0oM3H17Lth"
    ]
   },
   "targeting": {
    "regions": [
     "US"
    ]
   }
  },
```

Is there any way to fetch only items with specific region?

Thanks for any help.

Comment: So you want to modify query to get only results from specific regions ?

Comment: @Random: Yes, that's what I want if there is any way. I don't want to fetch all data and then filter them on client side. It would cost lots of time to fetch all data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't filter these channel sections in your query like that. What you'd have to do is get the list of `ChannelSections` from that channel, store it in an object, and check if the targeted region for each channel section matches what you want (i.e. the value in [targeting.regions[]](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/channelSections#targeting.regions[]) equals `XX`, where `XX` is the region you're looking for). Then, you could store the channel sections that you wanted to find into an array and return that. If you're concerned about time, you'd have to set up a server that can do all of that for you.

Comment: This sadly seems to be the only solution. There is no parameter to filter targeting value in the request query. Thank you.